# Cannot Basic Auth from React App with Axios or SuperAgent

Tags: reactjs, basic-authentication, axios, superagent

I try to make a GET request with axios and I always get 401. This happens only when I send the request from my react app.

```
axios.get('http://localhost:8080/vehicles', {
        withCredentials: true,
        auth: {
            username: 'admin',
            password: 'admin'
        },
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
    })
```

Postman GET request with the same credentials and Basic Auth set, works.

If I simply type in my browser the url, a login box appears and with the same credentials, it works, I get what I want.

I tried with SuperAgent too:

```
Request.get("http://localhost:8080/vehicles")
        .withCredentials()
        .auth('admin', 'admin')
        .then(response => {
            return response.body
        });
```

Still nothing.

I saw a question related to this one but no one answered it.

([Basic authentication : failure supergaent+OSX , success on superagent+Redhat , success on Postman+OSX,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40064018/basic-authentication-failure-supergaentosx-success-on-superagentredhat-s))

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: I feel ya, bro. I have the same issue and I'm googling like a maniac... nothing!

Comment: i managed it somehow with superangent requesting a `get request` on a path where `auth` is needed, `.withCredentials()
            .auth(this.state.user, this.state.password)
            .end((err, res) =>{});`, and after that on every request just using .withCredentials(), without .auth again.

Comment: I see. In my case the problem was on the server side, OPTIONS response didn't come with ALLOW ORIGIN header. That was the problem :)